# Running android unit tests via robolectric plugin

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

I am trying to run android unit tests via robolectric gradle plugin.

I am getting the following error for some of my tests.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource path must end in "/res"
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:224)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:175)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource path must end in "/res"
    at org.robolectric.res.PackageResourceLoader.<init>(PackageResourceLoader.java:20)
    at org.robolectric.res.PackageResourceLoader.<init>(PackageResourceLoader.java:11)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createResourceLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:605)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createAppResourceLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:594)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getAppResourceLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:585)
    at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:89)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:404)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:220)
```

Does anyboy know how to fix this?

I am using gradle version `1.12`

Suggestion provided [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin) did not work for me

Comment: What code causes this error?

Comment: I am not exactly sure I just have some basic robolectric related configuration

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug/restriction in robolectric, you might find [some info here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/pull/744)

Comment: I read this thread already but didn't give me enough information to fix the issue. The thread mainly says that we are removing this restriction via this github issue and it seems to be fixed in robolectric 2.3. But I cant move to robolectric 2.3 right away.